# Is there a way to click a single icon and open multiple application at once?

Tags: macos, applications, dock

When I use Mac, I tend to have to open a stack of applications at once, specifically:

- Unity Hub
- Visual Studio
- Terminal
- Opera

OR

- MAMP
- Visual Studio Code
- Opera
- Terminal

So I was thinking about adding an icon on the dock or on the desktop to start all these applications with a single click. Is there a way?

Up to now I just found a way to do this with BASH, but I should run it from the terminal...

Comment: Abother way is to note you don't need to shut things down. Let the OS deal with inactive apps by swapping them out. (I do find web browsers are an exception and you need to close them every now and then)

Comment: @mmmmmm I really don't understand what you mean, but the given answer is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use **Automator** to create a *workflow* as an *application*, adding as many **Launch Application** *actions* as you wish. I'd also add a **Pause** *action* in between.

You can then drag the *application* from **Finder** onto the **Dock** if you wish.

[image]

---

Or you could use **AppleScript** in **Script Editor**, saved as an *application*, using as many `tell application "appName" to launch` *statements*.  I'd also add a `delay` *command* in-between each.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
property appNamesList : {"Chess", "Contacts", "Dictionary", "Font Book"}

repeat with appName in appNamesList
    tell application appName to launch
    delay 2
end repeat
```

Comment: Quick question: why should I put a pause?

Comment: @ZioCain, RE: "terminal is not among the listed application, where do I find it? Also: why should I put a pause? " --  In the _pop-up list_ scroll down to **Other…** and then navigate to **Applications** > **Utilities** > **Terminal**.  The reason for the **Pause** _action_ is so you don't hammer the **CPU**, however you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you! I did find the Terminal! - The pause thing doesn't seem to be a problem, but will add it if needed.

Answer (score 4):

If you did not have a bash script already, I'd tell you to do as per the [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/430494/9314) given by [user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894.).

But if your already have a bash script (say, named `~/open_apps.sh`), you can create an Apple Script with the Script Editor application that says:

```applescript
do shell script "~/open_apps.sh"
```

And then, Save the script to your Desktop, for instance, using Application as the file format, leaving unchecked the checkboxes for Show startup screen and Stay open after run handler.

After that, you can now launch that script (and hence your applications) by double clicking your new AppleScript application.

Answer (score 2):

I do this by adding apps to the Login Items for my user in the Users & groups panel in System Settings.

When I log in they start.

Comment: Yeah, that could work, but I don't need them to be opened at login everytime

Comment: @ZioCain no problem, just thought it was an option that may help others. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make a `.command` file.  This is a shell script, but you can run it by opening it from the Finder.

Put this in a text file called `openThings.command`:

```
open /Applications/TextEdit.app
open /Applications/Stocks.app
```

If you want to be gentle, you could:

```
open /Applications/TextEdit.app
sleep 1
open /Applications/Stocks.app
```

And make it executable: `chmod +x openThings.command`.

Now you can double-click that in the Finder to run it.

Comment: This answer, as currently written, fails to execute properly on **macOS Catalina** and later. Take time to read the _manual page_ for the `open` _command_ as the `-a` _option_ is supposed to be used when opening an _application_. While this method of opening _applications_ works when properly coded, nonetheless, it leaves a useless **Terminal** _window_ open that one then has to close. The other answers do not suffer from this shortcoming. IMO This method is not at all what the OP had in mind as he could have just double click his existing _shell script_ and ended up with the same results.

Comment: I'm still on Mojave here, but double-clicking a `.sh` file just opens it in TextEdit.  Do later versions of macOS act differently?

Comment: Just to name a few, like the 200+ **POSIX shell script text executable, ASCII text** _files_ in `/usr/bin`, only one of which has an `.sh` _file extension_, I do the same as **Apple** and not needlessly give my executable shell scripts an `.sh` extension and if _doubled-click_ in **Finder** do the exact same as you've described adding `.command`. I think most would agree one does not want to have to close a non-active _window_ from **Terminal** every time under the conditions expressed in the question when tying to simplify an automated process.